# Issue with reqirep param in haproxy configuration

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

My current url is

```
http://10.24.23.20/textr/mine.php
```

and through haproxy rewrite url, I want to transfer that to

```
http://10.24.23.20/#/textr/mine.php`
```

for this I used following reqirep rules and none worked

1. `reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /textr/(.*) \1\ /\#/textr/\2`
2. `reqirep ^(\b\w{4}://10.24.23.20/)\ (\btextr/.*) \1\#/\2`

First one converts the url like `http://10.24.23.20/textr/mine.php#/`
second one simply fails to do anything.

Can someone please help me out on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question without proper research.. First transformation format I mentioned in the question itself worked fine..

reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /textr/(.*) \1\ /#/textr/\2

Mistake was that I incorrectly added spaces in between in my haproxy.cfg file. Once I clear that all started working and the URL is transformin with # inbetween the server and base folder